# How do you know an image specified in SVG has fully loaded?

Tags: html, svg

I have the following SVG document embedded in my HTML markup:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="00%" x2 ="0" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect y="0.3" width="1" height=".7" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".35" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image id="coverImage" xlink:href="/images/v3/eminem-cover.jpg" width="200" height="200" mask="url(#masking)" />
</svg>
```

How do I know when `#coverImage` has been loaded (i.e., it has been retrieved from the network?) Usually you could just check the `complete` property on the element, but since this isn't an `HTMLImageElement`, there is no such property.

Comment: Well you could maybe just create a `new Image` object in JavaScript with the same `src` URL, and check when that has loaded …

Answer (score 1):

SVG supports a number of DOM events, including onload.

```
<image xlink:href="/images/v3/eminem-cover.jpg" ... onload="doSomething();" />
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html

Comment: How do I know if the image is already loaded? Is there an appropriate state variable?

Comment: The onload event should be called either way.

Comment: First, this is the right way to do it. SVG2 requires that load events fire for elements that load external resources, such as <image>. However, some browsers don't do that at the moment, Firefox doesn't fire load for <image> for example. See testcase: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/events/load-events/image-root.svg